# Kubernetes - Ingress configuration, two paths redirects to different namespaces

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress, azure-aks

Im struggling with the ingress configuration that will allow accessibility from two **different paths** to services which are deployed on **different namespaces**.

1# Ingress:

```
    # Source: deployment/templates/ingress.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: portal-api
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: deployment-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: deployment
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: portal-api
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "0.0.1"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  annotations:
    certmanager.k8s.io/acme-challenge-type: http01
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    kuberentes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - "example.com"
      secretName: portal-certificate
  rules:
    - host: "example.com"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/rest/(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: portal-api
              servicePort: 80
```

## 2 Ingress

```
# Source: deployment/templates/ingress.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: portal-ui
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: deployment-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: deployment
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: portal-ui
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "0.0.1"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  annotations:
    certmanager.k8s.io/acme-challenge-type: http01
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - "example.com"
      secretName: portal-certificate
  rules:
    - host: "example.com"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: portal-ui
              servicePort: 80
```

Routing for path example.com - works, its redirect to portal-ui.
Routing for path example.com/api/rest/(something) - doesnt works, its redirect to portal-ui service.

I think that It will works on the same namespace... But i need two namespaces for each service.

Answer (score 3):

As @Arghya Sadhu mentioned

> Ingress and its corresponding service need to be in same namespace otherwise ingress cannot discover endpoints from the service.

There is a [github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/17088) opened since 2015 and there is still discuss how to make it work.

For now it´s **either to create ingress in the same namespace**

**Example made by github issue member @aledbf**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: component1
  namespace: component1
spec:
  rules:
  - host: domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: component1
          servicePort: 80
        path: /component1
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1


kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: component2
  namespace: component2
spec:
  rules:
  - host: domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: component2
          servicePort: 80
        path: /component2
```

---

**OR**

---

**You could try [workaround](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/17088#issuecomment-394313647) made by github issue member @chestack**

> my workaround:
>
> serviceA in namespaceA
>
> create serviceB in namespaceB

```
spec:
    ...
    type: ExtertalName
    externalName: serviceA.namespaceA.svc.cluster.local
```

> add ingress rule into ingressB in namespaceB

```
- path: /****
        backend:
          serviceName: serviceB
          servicePort: ***
```

Answer (score 2):

Ingress and its corresponding service need to be in same namespace otherwise ingress cannot discover endpoints from the service. So create ingress1, service1 in namespace1 and ingress2, service2 in namespace2.